# Socket IO Node to broadcast data to all clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, webgl

I am developing a WebGL multiplayer game. I try to implement multiplayer by socket.io, with express in node.js. When the user presses any key, the key event is first sent to server then the server should broadcast using socket to all the clients, like when the user presses key, the movement of the character should be visible to all of the client's browsers, but however right now with my code only the browser in which the client presses key the movement of character occurs.

I have provided my code here

https://github.com/kshitizrimal/helpGl

Please help me with this situation

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update all clients using Socket.io?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352164/update-all-clients-using-socket-io)

Comment: Its chatpage.jade .. its in my repo

Answer (score 0):

You are using express 2.x syntax. You must change the syntax for express v3. See this [page](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x#socketio-compatibility)

> Socket.IO's .listen() method takes an http.Server instance as an
>   argument. As of 3.x, the return value of express() is not an
>   http.Server instance. (See the Application function section above.) To
>   get Socket.IO working with Express 3.x, make sure you manually create
>   and pass your http.Server instance to Socket.IO's .listen() method.

This is how you would do it with express3 and socket.io

```
var express = require('express')
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```